# Fixing width in SlidingTabStrip android

Tags: android, user-interface

In the example provided by Android, [SlidingTabsBasic](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html), is it possible to have tabs with equal width ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed by making the following change in SlidingTabLayout.java

tabView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

Source:[Comments on +AndroidDeveleopers](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/X8fg63wK6S8)